# Problem importing .png files with transparencies to Flash Mx

Tags: png, adobe-flash

I can´t import .png files with transparencies to Flash Mx, it says that if I want to import the hole pictures of the sequence and later that the import did not finish because an unknown error occurred. 
So, I think that if I change the image to .gif or something it could work but I´m not sure if .gif saves the transparencies??

What can I do??

Thanks for answer.

Comment: Flash MX? Isn't that about a decade old now? (Still a valid question of course)

Comment: you can save gif with transparencies, and import them into mx. I used to do it all the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have access to Photoshop you can try using the save-for-web tools and saving as a png-24 (better for transparency but higher file size) or png-8 (smaller file size transparency isn't as crisp) hopefully one of those will import correctly

Alternatively depending on the image your trying to import you could try recreating it in flash - obviously this wont work for photo's - but for something like a logo this can easily be achieved.